# Get Error while refreshing bootstrap-select

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-select

i use of bootsrap-select

I get this error when I refer to Bootstrap-select

error is :TypeError: this.$element.find(...)[0] is undefined

when refresh: $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');

Thankful

Answer (score 0):

i fixed this error

We give an id to the tag and use that id to refer to it.

```html
<select id="selectid" class="selectpicker">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>
```

now for refresh

```js
$('#selectid').selectpicker('refresh');
```